# Node.js сервер вместо ответа отдает html файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Первый раз создал сервер на ноде и не совсем понимаю что происходит в прод. режиме
Приложение на связке реакт+нода. По идее, бэк нужен только для ручки - постучаться по урлам и отдать клиенту данные как есть. В дев версии все работает отлично - запросы отдаются без проблем. На прод версии, когда идет через build версию работа - запросы падают как 304. В консоли браузера тестил по запросам через xhr - Отдает просто html страницу.
Ниже - запрос из клиента, после нодовский app.js
Важно, сервер сам разворачивается и отдает по урлу index.html нормально

```js
export const getDataFromServer = async (url: string, opt = 'GET') => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(url, {
            method: opt,
        });
        return await response.json();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('cannot get data');
    }
}
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const path = require('path')
const request = require('request-promise');
const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000;

const app = express();
const url = 'some URL';
const serverOne = 'some URL';
const serverTwo = 'some URL';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    })
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('success');
});

app.get('/api/vk', async (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url
    }
    request(options).then((resp) => {
        res.send(resp);
    }).catch(() => {
        res.send('cant get vk info');
    });
});

app.get('/api/serverOne', async (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: serverOne
    }
    request(options).then((resp) => {
        res.send(resp);
    }).catch(() => {
        res.send('cant get server info');
    });
});

app.get('/api/serverTwo', async (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: serverTwo
    }
    request(options).then((resp) => {
        res.send(resp);
    }).catch(() => {
        res.send('cant get server info');
    });
});
```

Comment: Я мало знаком с нодой, но очевидно, что проблема в блоке `if process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` – либо `app.get('*'` ловит все запросы, либо `app.use('/'` (статику обычно вешают по URI префиксу `/static/`).

Comment: используйте next.js дабы не мучатся